# How to look through column names in R and perform operations then store it in a list of unknown row size

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe, matrix

I am a new R programmer and am trying to create a loop through a large amount of columns to weigh data by a certain metric.

I have a large data set of variables (some factors, some numerics). I want to loop through my columns, determine which one is a factor, and then if it is a factor I would like to use some tapply functions to do some weighting and return a mean. I have established a function that can do this one at a time here:

```
weight.by.mean <- function(metric,by,x,funct=sum()){

if(is.factor(x)){
a <- tapply(metric, x, funct)
b <- tapply(by, x, funct)
return (a/b)
} 
}

I am passing in the metric that I want to weigh and the by argument is what 
I am weighting the metric BY. x is simply a factor variable that I would 
like to group by.
```

Example: I have 5 donut types (my argument *x*) and I would like to see the mean dough (my argument *metric*) used by donut type but I need to weigh the dough used by the amount (argument *by*) of dough used for that donut type.

In other words, I am trying to avoid skewing my means by not weighting different donut types more than others (maybe I use a lot of normal dough for glazed donuts but dont use as much special dough for cream filled donuts. I hope this makes sense!

This is the function I am working on to loop through a large data set with many possible different factor variables such as "donut type" in my prior example. It is not yet functional because I am not sure what else to add. Thank you for any assistance you can provide for me. I have been using R for less than a month so please keep that in mind.

My end goal is to output a matrix or data frame of all these different means but each factor may have anywhere from 5 to 50 different levels so the row size is dependent on the number of levels of each factor.

```
weight.matrix <- function(df,metric,by,funct=sum()){


  n <- ncol(df) ##Number of columns to iterate through
  ColNames <- as.matrix(names(df))
  OutputMatrix <- matrix(1, ,3,nrow=, ncol=3)

 for(i in 1:n){


 if(is.factor(paste("df$",ColNames[i], sep=""))){
  a[[i]] <- tapply(metric, df[,i], funct)
  b[[i]] <- tapply(by, df[,i], funct)
}
OutputMatrix <- (a[[i]]/b[[i]])
}
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of your factors has different levels, then it would make more sense to use a long data frame instead of a wide one. For example:

```
Metric      Value        Mean
DonutType   Glazed       3.0
DonutType   Chocolate    5.2
DonutSize   Small        1.2
DonutSize   Medium       2.3
DonutSize   Large        3.6
```

Data frames are not meant for vectors of different lengths. If you want to store your data in a data frame, you need to organize it so all the vector lengths are the same. `gather()` and `spread()` are functions from the `tidyverse` package you can use to convert between long and wide data frames.

Comment: This is exactly the visualization that I desire. I could potentially have many different metrics so being able to perform this on 3 columns but with a variable number of rows is exactly what I am trying to accomplish. I will look into that package.

Comment: @Coldchain9 if this answer was helpful, please vote it up or accept it as the answer to your question. Thanks!